# Flatten results from hierachical XML file using Linq to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I currently have the following C# with Linq to XML code working but I'm hoping there is a better way to form the Linq query to then be able to extract the results into a flat structure.

Here are the current results formatted as I would like them to appear:

```
7990697: result_status = Complete
7990756: result_status = Incomplete
```

I want to be able to access the results using the syntax result.resultStatusId instead of result.meta.ToList()[0].resultStatusId

```
    var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(@"<fs_response status='success' timestamp='2014-07-10 14:38:39'>
<headings>
<heading for='result_status'>Result Status</heading>
<heading for='1'>First Name</heading>
<heading for='2'>Last Name</heading>
</headings>
<results>
<result id='7990697'>
<metas>
<meta id='result_status'>Complete</meta>
</metas>
<items>
<item id='1' index='3' type='text'>
<value>Bugs</value>
</item>
<item id='2' index='4' type='text'>
<value>Bunny</value>
</item>
</items>
</result>
<result id='7990756'>
<metas>
<meta id='result_status'>Incomplete</meta>
</metas>
<items>
<item id='1' index='3' type='text'>
<value>Yogi</value>
</item>
<item id='2' index='4' type='text'>
<value>Bear</value>
</item>
</items>
</result>
</results>
<total_results>2</total_results>
</fs_response>");

    var results =
    from x in xDoc.Elements("fs_response").Elements("results").Elements("result")
    select new
    {
        id = x.Attribute("id").Value,
        meta = from m in x.Elements("metas").Elements("meta")
               where m.Attribute("id").Value == "result_status"
               select new
               {
                   resultStatusId = m.Attribute("id").Value,
                   resultStatus = m.Value
               }
    };

    results.Dump();

    foreach (var result in results.ToList())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} = {2}", 
            result.id, 
            result.meta.ToList()[0].resultStatusId, 
            result.meta.ToList()[0].resultStatus);
        //Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} = {2}", 
        //    result.id, 
        //    result.resultStatusId, 
        //    result.resultStatus);
    }
```

Comment: you can use `result.meta.`[First()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb291976(v=vs.110).aspx)`.resultStatusId`, also see [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.110).aspx) extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var results =
        from x in xDoc.Elements("fs_response").Elements("results").Elements("result")
        from m in x.Elements("metas").Elements("meta")
        where m.Attribute("id").Value == "result_status"
        select new
        {
        id = x.Attribute("id").Value,
        resultStatusId = m.Attribute("id").Value,
        resultStatus = m.Value,
        };

    foreach (var result in results.ToList())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} = {2}", result.id, result.resultStatusId, result.resultStatus);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change the query to something like this:

```
var results = xDoc.Element("fs_response")
                  .Element("results")
                  .Elements("result")
                  .Select (e => new
                  {
                      id = e.Attribute("id").Value,
                      meta = e.Element("metas")
                              .Elements("meta")
                              .Where (m =>
                                  m.Attribute("id").Value == "result_status")
                              .Select (m => new
                              {
                                  resultStatusId = m.Attribute("id").Value,
                                  resultStatus = m.Value
                              })
                              .Single()
                  });
```

Some notes:

- Notice the change in a few locations from `Elements` to `Element`. This indicates that you know there will only be one result with that name, or if you only want the first with that name. Use `Elements` when you expect multiple results. In some cases in the example above, I'm making assumptions about your xml schema (such as the fact that there will only be one `metas` Element per result). This may perform faster as it will not have to continue searching for Elements of a specific name once it has found one.
- Also see the use of `Single()`. This indicates that you are expecting one and *only* one  element with the `id` attribute equal to `result_status`. If you expect 0 or 1, you can use `SingleOrDefault()`, or if you want the first in a potential list of matching elements you can use `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()`. Once you add this, you will no longer have to call `ToList()[0]` in the results:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} = {2}", 
    result.id, 
    result.meta.resultStatusId, 
    result.meta.resultStatus);
```